# Elasticsearch Update Doc String Replacement

Tags: regex, string, elasticsearch

I have some documents on my Elasticsearch. I want to update my document contents by using String Regexp.

For example, I would like to replace all http words into https words, is it possible ?

Thank You

Comment: You don't need regexes to replace http by https.

Comment: So, what can I do ?

Answer (score 10):

This should get you off to a start. Check out the "Update by Query" API [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/docs-update-by-query.html). The API allows you to include the update script and search query in the same request body.

Regarding your case, an example might look like this...

`POST addresses/_update_by_query`

```
{
    "script":
    {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "ctx._source.data.url = ctx._source.data.url.replace('http', 'https')"
    },
    "query":
    {
        "query_string":
        {
            "query": "http://*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty self explanatory, but `script` is where we do the update, and `query` returns the documents to update.

Painless supports regex so you're in luck, look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-examples.html) for some examples, and update the `inline` value accordingly.

Comment: Updated doc link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html